# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (256x16 and 4096x1024)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am new to Deep Learning and have created a model to classify my images.

Currently, this project raises an error on Google Colab or Kaggle (CPU and GPU) but not on my personal computer (with CPU).

Model:

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(CNN,self).__init__()
    self.network1 = nn.Sequential(

        nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
        # nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((128,128)),
    
        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(128 ,128, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2,2),
        
        nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d((4,4))
    )

    self.network2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(256*4*4, 1024),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(1024, 512),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(512, n_classes)
    )

    self.sigm = nn.Sigmoid()

  def forward(self,x):
    x = self.network1(x)
    x = self.network2(x)

    return self.sigm(x)
```

Training:

```
epoch = 0

model.train()
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

while True:
    batch_losses = []
    
    for imgs, labels in data:
        imgs, labels = imgs.float().to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        model_result = model(imgs)
        loss = criterion(model_result, labels.type(torch.float))

        batch_loss_value = loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        batch_losses.append(batch_loss_value)


    loss_value = np.mean(batch_losses)
    print("epoch:{:2d} iter:{:3d} train: loss:{:.3f}".format(epoch, iteration, loss_value))
    if epoch % SAVE_FREQ == 0:
        checkpoint_save(model, epoch)
    epoch += 1
    if EPOCHS < epoch:
        break
```

ERROR:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/872363799.py in <module>
     14         optimizer.zero_grad()
     15 
---> 16         model_result = model(imgs)
     17         loss = criterion(model_result, labels.type(torch.float))
     18 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1108         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/tmp/ipykernel_33/1050848783.py in forward(self, x)
     32     self.sigm = nn.Sigmoid()
     33   def forward(self,x):
---> 34     x = self.network(x)
     35     return self.sigm(x)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1108         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
    139     def forward(self, input):
    140         for module in self:
--> 141             input = module(input)
    142         return input
    143 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1108         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    101 
    102     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 103         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    104 
    105     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (256x16 and 4096x1024)
```

Input shape is (3, 406, 565)
The summary for this model with this shape is:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1         [-1, 32, 406, 565]             896
              ReLU-2         [-1, 32, 406, 565]               0
            Conv2d-3         [-1, 64, 406, 565]          18,496
              ReLU-4         [-1, 64, 406, 565]               0
         MaxPool2d-5         [-1, 64, 203, 282]               0
            Conv2d-6        [-1, 128, 203, 282]          73,856
              ReLU-7        [-1, 128, 203, 282]               0
            Conv2d-8        [-1, 128, 203, 282]         147,584
              ReLU-9        [-1, 128, 203, 282]               0
        MaxPool2d-10        [-1, 128, 101, 141]               0
           Conv2d-11        [-1, 256, 101, 141]         295,168
             ReLU-12        [-1, 256, 101, 141]               0
           Conv2d-13        [-1, 256, 101, 141]         590,080
             ReLU-14        [-1, 256, 101, 141]               0
AdaptiveAvgPool2d-15            [-1, 256, 4, 4]               0
          Flatten-16                 [-1, 4096]               0
           Linear-17                 [-1, 1024]       4,195,328
             ReLU-18                 [-1, 1024]               0
           Linear-19                  [-1, 512]         524,800
             ReLU-20                  [-1, 512]               0
           Linear-21                   [-1, 18]           9,234
          Sigmoid-22                   [-1, 18]               0
================================================================
Total params: 5,855,442
Trainable params: 5,855,442
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 2.63
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 712.84
Params size (MB): 22.34
Estimated Total Size (MB): 737.80
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Solution

In my case, the problem was that I didn't consider the batch size in my image shape and that my dataset had few images with grayscale and few with an alpha channel.

Comment: What is the shape of `imgs`?

Comment: @jhso imgs can take a variable shape between (3,16,16) to (3,540,960). Therefore, there is an AdaptiveAvgPool2d layer in front of the Flatten layer, which ensures that the variable shape becomes a uniform shape for the Linear layer.

Comment: Is this batched? ie. is the shape of the actual `imgs` variable `(X,3,H,W)` (h=height, w=width)? If this does not have a fourth batch dimension then this is where your issue is coming from. I suspect this is the case because your channel dimension is acting as the batch in your error message. My recommendation: use a dataloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was that first of all I didn't consider the batch size in my image shape and secondly that my dataset had few images with grayscale and few with an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Then the Error provided by you is not align with your code. In the Error there is:

```
/tmp/ipykernel_33/1050848783.py in forward(self, x)
     32     self.sigm = nn.Sigmoid()
     33   def forward(self,x):
---> 34     x = self.network(x)
     35     return self.sigm(x)
```

But the code you provide is:

```py
  def forward(self,x):
    x = self.network1(x)
    x = self.network2(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but the model already has a Flatten layer built in.
It is in the network2 the first layer.